# Alternative way to find the eigenvalues of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

I am trying questions of Masters of Mathematics Entrance exam of my university and I am looking for an alternative solution for this question.

> Find Eigenvalue of the Matrix
> $$ 
>     \begin {bmatrix}
>     1 & 1 & 2 \\
>     1 & -2 & -5 \\
>     2 & 5 & -3 \\
>     \end {bmatrix} 
> $$
> Options
>
> - $-4, 3,-3$
> - $4,3,1$
> - $4,-4+\sqrt{13} , -4-\sqrt{13}$
> - $4,-2+\sqrt{7} , -2-\sqrt{7}$

I know that one way to find eigenvalues is using [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) and then equating characteristic polynomial to $O$ .

But since Exam is Objective and Not Subjective, Is there any way to find Eigenvalues without using Cayley-Hamilton theorem (as that method is Time-Consuming)?

If yes kindly shed some light.

**Edit:** All Four options given are same as options given in assignment. So, maybe question is wrong.

Comment: If you have to choose between 3 options, you should probably try to verify the eigenvalues instead of trying to find them. You can use the trace of your matrix to do that.

Comment: Oh! My bad! right @klaus

Comment: @User Maybe it would be helpful if you could show the 3 options to better understand the difficulty of the exam question. E.g. depending on the options, you could rule out some by considering the trace or the determinant.

Comment: @User Are you sure you are conveying the question correctly? None of these options are right.

Comment: @User The matrix as currently written has approximate eigenvalues $1.4523$ and $-2.7262 \pm 4.6354i$. I suspect that you have copied the question incorrectly

Comment: @User It is notable that of the available options, only (1) and (3) list eigenvalues whose sum is the trace of the matrix

Comment: Use the definition  $Av=\lambda v$? Though that's not the quickest way I guess.

Comment: This reminds me of an old incident. My boss once had some urgent business to attend to and he asked me to supervise an operations research exam for half an hour. Soon after the exam began, I realised that some entries in an array were wrong. *But I hadn't a cellphone*. What should I do? Luckily, I managed to figure out a possible correction on spot and my boss returned sooner than I expected, so that we could announce the correction early in the exam. But that was really a heck of a horror story to me in those days.

Comment: Option 3 is correct if you change the $(1,3)$-th entry from $-5$ to $5$.

Comment: @user1551 thanks a lot for your help. But as there was a mistake in question ( in the assignment itself( as no option is matching) ,not in typing here ) , so I think it's best to leave the question without answeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** try to find trace and det of the matrix $A$ , that will eliminate all other false options. [Rule : trace of $A$ = sum of all eigenvalues of $A$, det($A$)=multiplication of eigenvalues of $A$]

Comment: How do you intend to "eliminate all other false options" when all of the options given are false?

Comment: @Ben Grossmann I say, this way will lead!

Comment: This way will **not** "lead" because, as has been stated in the comments, none of the options provided are correct.

Comment: Note in particular that the matrix given has a determinant $42$. All choices given have a product of eigenvalues which is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann using the rule , what I given, by these, it easily can said that all options are wrong.

Comment: So, what the problem with answer!

Comment: Why am I devoted?? All options are wrong, but it doesn't make my answer wrong.

Comment: I downvoted you because your question does not answer the question being asked: "how can one efficiently pick out the correct question given this question on an exam?" Your answer *would* be correct if the choices given were such that the wrong choices could be eliminated based on the trace and determinant. However, because we have not seen the correct version of this question, we have no evidence that is the case.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann it has the correct version in the exam "Csir Ugc Net" held in India.

Comment: Is it possible to look at the questions to this exam online?

Comment: Hmmm, it's possible, year : June $2017$, you can download the paper.

Comment: If you could find a link to the exam and point to the problem being asked about, then that would certainly change what I've said

Comment: Same question, just replace $-5$ by $5$ in matrix!

Comment: Matrix, $$ 
    \begin {pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    1 & -2 & 5 \\
    2 & 5 & -3 \\
    \end {pmatrix} 
$$, options are same

Comment: Sorry for the edit, couldn't switch my vote otherwise

Comment: Please don't be sorry, you are so senior than me in knowledge!

Comment: Well, you have two equations in three unknowns (product of eigenvalues = determinant of matrix) and ( sum of eigenvalues = trace of matrix).  It is still possible of an incorrect answer to satisfy both of these equations.  What then?

Comment: I told those case for quick observation,, for an particular case,,as the problem is described in such particular pattern.    This quick observation is just for the eliminating false cases, not for finding the eigenvalues obviously, as we all know what the actual rule is to find that.